# Ideas on how to build a line sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor

I would like to detect a set of objects (width and height) as they pass through some sort of line sensor in a conveyor line. Something like this (transversal view):

[image: Sensor idea]

Not sure where to start...

1. What type of sensor is the right one this for this scenario?
2. Any thoughts on how to integrate a sensor like this into an Arduino board?
3. If nothing comes to mind, what other approach would you recommend?

Comment: what are the objects you are sensing made of?

Comment: and what's the min/max distance between the objects and the sensor?

Comment: What sort of resolution, both in height and length, do you need to achieve? Can you monitor/measure the movement of the conveyor?

Comment: Comments regarding the drawing.  Clever diagram for the output: +1.  But why is the vertical 6cm three times smaller than the horizontal 6cm?

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of line scan solutions available, all the way from cameras using cameralink interfaces and with ethernet interfaces for $6K to sensors from about 8 different manufacturers.

However, since you are mentioning Arduino, I'll assume that:

1) This is a one off project - there is no consideration for designing something

2) You want to spend as little as possible.

Typically the best (least expensive) result will be to use what is know as a CIS (Contact image sensor) module, which is the lowest cost that you'll be able to get.  The best place to get these is to buy a very inexpensive scanner and tear out the guts and repurposing it, it would have a USB interface to your Arduino then.  This would have the lights and everything you need.

The fundamental problem you have from your drawing is that there is no optics.  Even the scanner CIS module has some lenslets in from of the array but they only image very close to the array itself.  with the drawing as shown your just going to get a blur.  Perhaps it would work to get a scanner that has some lenses in it.  Some of the higher end ones do not use CIS modules but use lenses and CCD's.

The other alternative is to use a smaller section of the CIS array and to put it behind a SLR lens (35 mm - tons of used ones available) . Most machine/industrial imaging solutions tend to use similar lens types as those that are used for SLR, simply because of availability.  If you use a lens solution yo will have to have a lot higher stand off (distance of lens to object).

Comment: how would this detect height?

Comment: You can quantify how in focus something is with filtering e.g. laplacian of gaussian (LoG) filter

Answer (score 1):

How about an [IR line sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9453)? That will give you an analog voltage that can be read into the ADC on the Arduino board. If I understand your diagram correctly, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an infrared distance sensor such as [this model from Sharp](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/136) or an
ultrasonic distance sensor such as the [ping board](http://learn.parallax.com/KickStart/28015).  Depending on your budget, you can get much high resolution sensors.

Comment: There is no need to have lots of them placed side by side to have higher resolution. He can have the sensor move with a motor and some mechanics gathered from an old printer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to go with a adhoc. I suspect with a range of 6cm you will find the width of overlap of the UltraSonic or IR sensors a problem. You could use a [cheap laser tape measure with the following add-on](http://porcupineelectronics.com/site/mobile?url=http%3A%2F%2Fporcupineelectronics.com%2FLaserbotics.html)  to connect to your Arduino. Depending upon your costs and update requirements. You may need to either have multiple lasers or you could drive a servo (or something) to scanning mirror and scan the points of measurement. You may want another long shallow mirror across the range area as to eliminate (minimize) tangential errors.